# Type of Axios mock using jest typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs

I have the following method in a class:

```
import axios from 'axios'

public async getData() {
   const resp = await axios.get(Endpoints.DATA.URL)
   return resp.data
}
```

Then I am trying to set up a Jest test that does this:

```
jest.mock('axios')

it('make api call to get data', () => {
   component.getData()
   expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Endpoints.DATA.URL)
})
```

The problem is that because I am not mocking the return value, then it gives an error for `resp.data` because I'm calling `data` on `null` or `undefined` object. I spent at least 2 hours trying various ways to get this working but I can't find a way such that I can mock `axios.get` with some return value.

Jest's documentation uses JavaScript so they give this example [`axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) but I can't call `mockResolvedValue` because that method does not exist on `axios.get` in TypeScript.

Also, if you know other good testing library for React other than Jest that does this stuff easily for TypeScript, feel free to share.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In start of file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
```

Now you can use it as usual mock:

```
mockedAxios.get.mockRejectedValue('Network error: Something went wrong');
mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: {} });
```

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, but typescript is blaming my { data: null } with this error: `error TS2345: Argument of type '{ data: null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined) => AxiosPromise<T>) | PromiseLike<(<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined) => AxiosPromise<T>)>'.` No idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: you can try to type this or make any: `{ data: null } as any`

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please tell me your thought process or where did you find this solution. I want to understand this to be a better developer. const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'interceptors')` and `requestInstance.interceptors...`

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use `jest.mock` with `"no-any"` try this:

```
import axios, { AxiosStatic } from 'axios'

interface AxiosMock extends AxiosStatic {
  mockResolvedValue: Function
  mockRejectedValue: Function
}

jest.mock('axios')
const mockAxios = axios as AxiosMock

it('make api call to get data', () => {
   // call this first
   mockAxios.mockResolvedValue(yourValue)

   component.getData()
   expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Endpoints.DATA.URL)
})
```

Comment: This works and doesn't require another library, should be accepted answer

Comment: this approach works for me too, without the need to add new libraries. The only thing I am a bit stuck on is how to make it so that I don't have to repeat the same code in different test files.. will look into it and update the comment (hopefully)

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'interceptors')` and `requestInstance.interceptors`

Answer (score 11):

As of Jest `24.9.0` here is how it works correctly typing both `axios` and Jest properties.

What we would like for a typed mock is that the mocked object type contains the union of the mocked object type and the type of Jest mocks. As far as I seen non of the current answers enable that.

[jest.MockedFunction](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedfunction)

[jest.MockedClass](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedclass)

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios>;

mockedAxios.mockResolvedValue({ status: 200, data: 'mockResponse' });

// Or:
(mockedAxios.get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof mockedAxios.get>).mockResolvedValue('mockResponse');
```

As you can see, you can either manually cast what you need or you'll need something to traverse all axios properties/methods to type everything.

To do that (deep mock types) you can use [jest.mocked()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedtitem-t-deep--false) introduced in Jest `27.4.0`

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');

const mockedAxios = jest.mocked(axios, true); 

mockedAxios.mockImplementation() // correctly typed
mockedAxios.get.mockImplementation() // also correctly typed
```

Comment: As of Jest `29.0.0`, `jest.mocked` is default deep mocked. To invert this behavior, use `jest.mocked(axios, {shallow:true})`

Answer (score 8):

This is what I personally always use.

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios')

it('...', () => {
  (axios.get as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({}));
  // test here
  expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I kept running into `is not a function` issues. If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, then try importing `axios` with a capital A ie. `Axios`.

```
import Axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('Axios');
const mockedAxios = Axios as jest.Mocked<typeof Axios>;
```

Comment: I have no idea why it works, but it helped me - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> but I can't call mockResolvedValue because that method does not exist on axios.get in TypeScript

You can use an assertion:

```
(axios.get as any).mockResolvedValue(resp)
```

Comment: The project has a ts-lint rule `"no-any": true`

Comment: add a tslint ignore on the line before

Comment: 1. That's not going to be ideal as the project grows and more asynchronous calls are added. 2. I am using TypeScript for its strong type system and I don't want to circumvent it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a neat solution using the [`sinon`](http://sinonjs.org/) library `npm install sinon @types/sinon --save-dev`.

Then the testing code becomes:

```
let component: Component
let axiosStub: SinonStub

beforeAll(() => {
    component = new Component({})
    axiosStub = sinon.stub(axios, 'get')
})

afterAll(() => {
    axiosStub.restore()
})

it('make api call to get data', async () => {
    // set up behavior
    axiosStub.withArgs(Endpoints.DATA.URL).returns({data: []})

    // method under test
    const res = await component.getData()

    // assertions
    expect(res).toEqual([])
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```
import axios from "axios";

jest.spyOn(axios, "get").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({data: []}));
```

This also gives you the benefit of having a mocked method that you can test against, for example:

```
import axios from "axios";

// ...

const mockedGet = jest
  .spyOn(axios, "get")
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({data: []}));

// ...

expect(mockedGet).toBeCalledWith('https://example.api?q=abc&k=123');
```