# Jest mocking: TypeError: axios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have 2 versions of the same code, one works, one throws:

```
TypeError: axios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function
```

Works:

```
const axios = require('axios')
jest.mock('axios') //<<<------

test('should mock axios', async () => {
  const resp = {data: {moreData: 'zedata'}}
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp)
  const actualresp = await getAxios()
  expect(actualresp).toEqual({moreData: 'zedata'})
})
```

Doesn't:

```
const axios = require('axios')

test('should mock axios', async () => {
  jest.mock('axios') //<<<------
  const resp = {data: {moreData: 'zedata'}}
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp)
  const actualresp = await getAxios()
  expect(actualresp).toEqual({moreData: 'zedata'})
})
```

Can someone help me understand why moving `jest.mock('axios')` inside the testblock (or inside any function, for that matter) results in an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of Axios mock using jest typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275434/type-of-axios-mock-using-jest-typescript)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Jest has clearly addressed how to mock a module in this link https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules.

It has an important note as following:

> Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to be in the same scope as the require/import statement.

On the other hand, Most of use cases `jest.mock` is supposed to be called at the top level of module should work properly:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
// At the same scope with `require`
jest.mock('axios');
```

Comment: Thanks I missed this. Was looking at a different part of their docs.

Comment: can't believe this is still useful in 2022...

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to explicitly declare `axios.get` a mock function:

```
axios.get = jest.fn();
```

This adds `mockResolvedValue` and other functions to `axios.get`.