# How to resolve "TypeError: mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function" error?

Tags: typescript, axios, ts-jest

I am using `Jest` for my `TypeScript` project. I am trying to mock `Axios` but keep getting `TypeError: mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function` error. I have tried several ways as belows but not sure what am I doing wrong here.

I see some articles in this website about similar issue but when I try this on my side, I am unable to reslove it.

References:

- [Jest mocking: TypeError: axios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844580/jest-mocking-typeerror-axios-get-mockresolvedvalue-is-not-a-function)
- [Type of Axios mock using jest typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275434/type-of-axios-mock-using-jest-typescript)

**Code:**

`httpRequest.service.ts`

```
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import axios from 'axios';

@injectable()
export default class HttpService {
  /**
     * Generic function to make HTTP calls.
     * @template T
     * @param [options]
     * @returns request
     */
  public async request<T>(options: object = {}): Promise<T> {
    return axios.request(options)
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
}
```

`httpRequest.service.spec.ts`

**Option-1 = using `AxiosResponse` from `axios`**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import HttpService from '../httpRequest.service';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

describe('httpService', () => {
  let httpService: HttpService;
  let mockedAxios: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.mock('axios');

    mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

    httpService = new HttpService();
  });

  describe('request', () => {
    it('successfully returns response', async () => {

      const axiosResponse: AxiosResponse = {
        data: {
          userId: 1,
          id: 1,
          title: 'mock title',
          body: 'mock body',
        },
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        config: {},
        headers: {},
      };

      //Mocking axios function rather than a method
      mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);

      //Act
      const result = await httpService.request();

      //Assert
      expect(result).toBe({
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: 'mock title',
        body: 'mock body',
      });

    });

  });
});
```

**Option-2 = using `mocked` from `ts-jest`**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import HttpService from '../httpRequest.service';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/dist/utils/testing';

describe('httpService', () => {
  let httpService: HttpService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.mock('axios');

    httpService = new HttpService();
  });

  describe('request', () => {
    it('successfully returns response', async () => {

      const axiosResponse: AxiosResponse = {
        data: {
          userId: 1,
          id: 1,
          title: 'mock title',
          body: 'mock body',
        },
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        config: {},
        headers: {},
      };

      //Mocking axios function rather than a method
      mocked(axios).mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);
      // mocked.get.mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);

      //Act
      const result = await httpService.request();

      //Assert
      expect(result).toBe({
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: 'mock title',
        body: 'mock body',
      });

    });

  });
});
```

**Option-3 = using `AxiosStatic` from `axios`**

```
import HttpService from '../httpRequest.service';
import axios, { AxiosStatic } from 'axios';

interface AxiosMock extends AxiosStatic {
  mockResolvedValue: any
  mockRejectedValue: any
}

describe('httpService', () => {
  let httpService: HttpService;
  let mockAxios: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.mock('axios');

    mockAxios = axios as AxiosMock;
    httpService = new HttpService();
  });

  describe('request', () => {
    it('successfully returns response', async () => {

      const axiosResponse: AxiosResponse = {
        data: {
          userId: 1,
          id: 1,
          title: 'mock title',
          body: 'mock body',
        },
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        config: {},
        headers: {},
      };

      //Mocking axios function rather than a method
      mockAxios.mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);

      //Act
      const result = await httpService.request();

      //Assert
      expect(result).toBe({
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: 'mock title',
        body: 'mock body',
      });

    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by making 2 changes in my `Option-1` solution:

1. Move `jest.mock('axios');` after import statement. I am not sure why it is not working when I declare it inside `beforeAll` (looking into this).
2. Change `mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);` to `mockedAxios.request.mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);`. This is a silly mistake where my function uses `.request` but I was mocking `.get`.

Here is full solution.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import HttpService from '../httpRequest.service';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');

describe('httpRequest', () => {
  let httpService: HttpService;
  let mockedAxios: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();

    mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
    httpService = new HttpService();

  });

  describe('request', () => {
    it('successful', async () => {

      const mockAxiosData = {
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: '',
        body: '',
      };

      const axiosResponse: AxiosResponse = {
        data: mockAxiosData,
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        config: {},
        headers: {},
      };

      mockedAxios.request.mockResolvedValue(axiosResponse);

      const request = await httpService.request();
      expect(request).toBe(mockAxiosData);

    });
  });

});
```

Comment: You may also need to explicitly declare `axios.request` a mock function:   `axios.request = jest.fn();`

This adds `mockResolvedValue` and other functions to `axios.request`.

Comment: Using jest 27, still encountering the same issue where I cannot call any methods on 'mockFetch' (trying to call 'mockImplementation' in my case)